# RTK Query polling only fixed number of times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to implement a polling with redux toolkit RTK Query.
My need is to execute the polling only a fixed number of times (this number of times comes from a preloaded configuration).
The process for the polling itself it's pretty simple and following the documentation I see that it is sufficient to add the options `pollingInterval` in the hook, but I don't understand how I can achive my need to execute the polling only a fixed number of times.

Here my service

*service.ts*

```
export const landingPageApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'landingPageApi',
    baseQuery: dynamicBaseQuery,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        ...,
        deepCheck: builder.query<HttpResponse<PaymentTransactionResponse>, { paymentId: string; deepCheck: boolean }>({
            query: ({ paymentId, deepCheck }) => `some-url`,
            async onQueryStarted(queryArg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                const { data } = await queryFulfilled
                const { payload } = data
                dispatch(updateTransactions(data.payload.transactionList ?? []))
            },
        })
    }),
})
```

and in my React component I use the auto-created hook `useDeepCheckQuery` and I try to execute the polling in this manner

*Component.tsx*

```
export function TransactionDetail(props: Props) {
    let pollingCount = 0;
    // some code ...
    const {} = useDeepCheckQuery(
         {
             paymentId: props.paymentId,
             deepCheck: pollingCount++ === 3,
         },
         {
             skip: pollingCount++ > 3 && !['PMT_IN_PRGS', 'PAYMENT_STARTED'].includes(props.transaction.status),
             pollingInterval: 3000,
         },
     )
```

but it doesn't work.

For example if the fixed number of times is 3, I need to execute the API call 3 times with the first 2 with the property `deepCheck=false` and the last call with the property `deepCheck=true`. In general I need that only the last call has the property `deepCheck` setted to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem. I have not found a solution yet, I will try your method for incrementing polling count. But I see a flaw in your initializing of polling count. It will always be 0 on each render. You need to put it in a `useState`.